# How can I control inputs on Shell Script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am getting parameters from user ./inputControl.sh param1 param2 ...
I want users can only enter numbers. can not enter any words, etc.

if they enter word i will show them error.

thanks for answers

Comment: DO you need to accept floats or just ints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash has half-decent support for regular expressions

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
param1=$1
param2=$2

number_regex="^[0-9]+$"

if ![[ $param1 ]] || [[ $param1 !~ $number_regex ]] ; then
    echo Param 1 must be a number
    exit 1
fi
if ![[ $param2 ]] || [[ $param2 !~ $number_regex ]] ; then
    echo Param 2 must be a number
    exit 1
fi
```

If you can also accept floating point numbers, then you could set `number_regex` to something like:

```
"^[+-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$"
```

or

```
"^[+-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?$"
```

(last two regexes are untested and may not be quite right).

Comment: And `"^[+-]?[0-9]+$"` to allow negative integers

Comment: I can't find any reference to `!~` and it doesn't work in my Bash 3.2. Your `if` statements can be rewritten and simplified to look like: if `[[ ! param1 || ! $param1 =~ $number_regex ]]`.

Answer (score 0):

example: check for numbers

```
$ echo 1234d | awk '{print $0+0==$0?"yes number":"no"}'
no
$ echo 1234 | awk '{print $0+0==$0?"yes number":"no"}'
yes number
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash regular expressions are handy, but they were only introduced in 3.1 and changed quoting rules in 3.2.

```
[[ 'abc' =~ '.' ]]  # fails in ≤3.0
                    # true in  =3.1
                    # false in ≥3.2
                    #   except ≥4.0 with "shopt -s compat31"
[[ 'abc' =~ . ]]    # fails in ≤3.0
                    # true in  ≥3.1
```

And they aren't even necessary in the first place!  [`expr`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html) has been a standard shell utility with regex support for forever, and is works on non-GNU and non-Bash systems.  (It uses [basic (old) regular expressions](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) like `grep`, not [extended (new) regular expressions](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) like `egrep`.)

```
expr 'abc' : '.'        # outputs '1' (characters matched), returns 0 (success)
expr 'abc' : '.\(.\).'  # outputs 'b' (group matched), returns 0 (success)
expr 'abc' : ....       # outputs '0', returns 1 (failure)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how you could do this easily. I would use perl or python scripting that provides regexp, it would be easier.